# Mailgan email validation message":"Validations are not enabled."

Tags: php, laravel, validation, mailgun

I'm trying to use Email validator from Mailgun in my laravel project.
I'm following the documentation here https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-email-validation.html#request-examples. But I'm always getting a message ": "Validations are not enabled.". I've tried the examples from the documentation for PHP and curl, but the result is the same "Validations are not enabled."

Does anyone know what is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Do you at least have the [Foundation plan](https://www.mailgun.com/pricing/) because the Flex one doesn't allow validations. If you do have that plan then you have to go into your Mailgun portal and activate it.

Comment: @hppycoder  thank you, you are right I missed it. But I was told that there is a sandbox server where I can try it. Do you know smth about it?